# Terraform Azure - Error while loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain provider schema:

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting below error after running terraform plan. I tried running below command but did not help :

```
terraform init - upgrade
terraform init
terraform plan

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

terraform plan

╷
│ Error: Failed to load plugin schemas
│
│ Error while loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm: failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm" to obtain schema:      
│ fork/exec .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/3.0.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.0.0_x5: exec      
│ format error..
```

There were some recommendations to Delete the terraform directory and lock file but i am not able to find it.Not seeing the files / folder after running terraform init.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once terraform `init` it will create `terraformtfstate` file, `terraform.loc.hcl` file and also a directory of the provider.

you can get those files under folder you have created for `main.tf` file..

[image]

Comment: But how to resolve above issue ?

Comment: You said there were recommendations to delete terraform directory and lock file. Fine the files as I have shown in my answer or delete it and then try it.

Comment: I dont see these folder/files after running terraform init. Attaching image in the post above

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when working [azapi](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Azure/azapi) azure partner provider in **Terraform**.

When I run the command:

```
terraform init
terraform plan
```

I get the error below:

> │ Error: failed to read schema for azapi_resource.container_apps_virtual_account_api_test in registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azapi: failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azapi" to obtain schema: unavailable provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azapi"

**Here's how I solved**:

I had previously setup a Azure container apps resource named `virtual_account_api_test` within this **Terraform** project. However, I deleted the Azure container apps resource using the **Azure Portal**, and then commented out the code for it in the Terraform script, in a bid to also have Terraform ask me if I want it deleted as well from my state file.

But that was not the case, rather Terraform could not read the schema for the resource.

All I had to do was to simply run the command below to remove the resource from the Terraform state file as well since it has already bee deleted:

```
terraform state rm azapi_resource.container_apps_virtual_account_api_test
```

Next, I ran the previous commands again:

```
terraform init
terraform plan
```

This time everything worked fine.